# How to configure blocks per node?

Tags: blocks

I'd like to build a Drupal 7 module that generates a block which contains (along with some static HTML to be used as template for a JavaScript library) *a node-specific value* to be passed on to a web service. (The web service will return relevant data for the contents of the node.)

How should a block receive node-specific data? Module configuration seems to be global, and blocks cannot be configured individually.

Should I modify the main content-type of the node by adding this "node-specific data" as an extra field even if this value is only used in my module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Block API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/7) to add the blocks

i.e:

- [hook_block_info](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)
- [hook_block_view](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

Use [menu_get_object](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) to get the node object for that page.

e.g:

```
function mymodule_block_view($delta){
  $block = array();
  switch($delta){
    case 'my_delta':
     if ($node = menu_get_object('node') && $node->type == 'my_type') {
       $block['subject'] = t('Example block on %node', array('%node' => $node->title));
       $block['content'] = render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'body')); // for example
     }
    break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```